# how can I grey out and show loading in the web page when user clicks on those items that are linked to next page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, loading

I created a php-html website with many pages, in these pages there are ,,, and other html elements, but not all of them linked to other pages, it means they do a job into the current page, but other elements are linked to other pages, how can I set when user clicks on those elements(,,...) that are linked to other pages,before going to next page the page be grey and loading.gif is shown.
I see this code
http://hungred.com/how-to/tutorial-simple-screen-grey-effect-jquery/

but in this jQuery code we need to set $('#button').click(pop); for thoese elements one by one,that I think it is not good job, what is the good idea, that works for whole pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution could be to apply the same class to all the buttons that need to act in this way:

```
<button class="externalLink">Button 1</button>
<button class="externalLink">Button 2</button>
<button class="externalLink">Button 3</button>
<button class="externalLink">Button 4</button>
<button class="externalLink">Button 5</button>
```

And then write something like this in javascript:

```
$('.externalLink').click(pop);
```

This will apply the same behavior to all the buttons with that class

Comment: dear Cirou thank you so much for your answer, but i have many pages with many elements, it is not possible that i add 'class="externalLink"' to thousands elements, is there a better approach that can implement on whole of webpages, that when user click on any element that is link to other pages, grey out function is loaded?

Comment: Please can you be more clear when you say: "any element that is link to other pages"? What kind of html elements are you talking about? There are also other elements like these that don't need to act this way?

Comment: <a>,<input><button>, ... or sometimes  <form>